# Information about circular sections of an oblique cone with conical base.

Tags: geometry, reference-request, book-recommendation, projective-geometry, advice

I'm looking for information in English about the topic of circular sections of an oblique cone with conical base since almost all the information on this topic is in French and there is little information. Could you please recommend me books or articles related with this?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is "conical base" a typo?

Comment: Apollonius treated the topic at the beginning of his "Conicae" but he was dealing with circular oblique cones.

Comment: Do you mean that the base is itself a conic section?

Comment: Do you have a precise question ?

Answer (score 1):

[archive.org](https://archive.org/) has an English translation of Chasles' memoir [Cones of the Second Degree](https://archive.org/details/twogeometricalm00gravgoog/page/n14), which are cones that have a conic as a base.  Salmon's [Conic Sections](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.162705/page/n341) also touches upon the topic.